# How to send a url-encoded form data using post request in bot-framework composer

Tags: bot-framework-composer

I have an API end-point which takes a query string as url-encoded form data and returns a json.

I have used `"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` as headers.

When I try sending `"query=xxx"` as body of http post call using composer I get an error in emulator saying "The parent is missing.".

When I try sending `{"query":"xxx"}` as body, I get an error in emulator saying :

> Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.

In which format should I send the data?

Answer (score 1):

You should send it like this:

```
URL:http://localhost:7071/api/GetStudentGrade
Body(string):studentID=${user.studentID}&coursecode=${user.coursecode}
Content type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Detailed image:

[image: usage example image]

Comment: thank you for this answer. This should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the body to an object, Also content type to application/json. Let me know if this resolves your issue.